# How do the round systems work?

Tags: teamfight-tactics

Seeing some preview matches of Teamfight Tactics, it seems the round system is not like in Autochess. In auto chess, the round are just a number, where in TFT it seems to use a 'Mario Bros' system.

Rounds are like 1-1,2-3,5-4, etc.

So what are the max number of rounds in a 'chapter' (to keep the Mario Bros analogy) and what is the logic for passing from a chapter to another?

Is it a fixed number of rounds per chapter (If so, how much?) , or does an event finish the chapter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each chapter (to keep using that terminology) has six rounds, except for the first, which starts with a draft pick (everyone picks at once) and then three minion rounds.

The fourth round of each chapter thereafter is a carrousel round where you can pick a champion in order of lowest to highest score thereafter. After the carrousel round, there is a PVP match in the same round. Comparing the screenshots below, the chapter looks like this after the carrousel part has finished (opponent's name has been blurred out):

[image]

Round six of every chapter except for the first is a monster round (Krugs, wolfs, Raptors, a dragon, Mechs, Rift Harold, the Elder Dragon, respectively).

All the other rounds are PVP.

To illustrate this, I took screenshots starting at the first chapter with PVP and ending at round six. <sub>Not showing rounds thereafter because all other players were eliminated by then. ;)</sub>

[image]

Source: [Rankboost](https://rankedboost.com/league-of-legends/teamfight-tactics/rounds/) (note that they use zero-based numbering and as indicated in a comment, they leave the chapters out altogether)

Answer (score 0):

The rounds, as far as I see, work like this.

Chapter 1 is a Carrousel, then 3 rounds of PVE.

Then, every other chapter works like this: 3 rounds of PVP against a random opponent, Carrousel, 2 rounds of PVP, then a PVE boss.

The boss is

- Chapter 2 : Crugs
- Chapter 3 : Wolves
- Chapter 4 : Raptors
- Chapter 5 : Drake
- Chapter 6 : Herald or Elder Drake
- Chapter 7 : Elder Drake

https://lolchess.gg/guide/rounds

Answer (score 0):

You can find a description of all the rounds and what to do in them, for example, on this site with [comps](https://seemeta.com/en/builds) for Teamfignt Tactics.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.